# Jquery não funciona com Angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bootstrap

Peguei uma Dashboard Bootstrap com Jquery, mas quando tento usa-lá com o single-page do `angularjs`, as funções que estão em jquery não funcionam, mas eu consigo fazer em angularjs, o que eu queria que funcionasse mesmo era o dropdown do menu-level, eu consegui fazer funcionar com bootstrap, mas não fica a mesma coisa

DropDown com Bootstrap

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dropdown com Jquery

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: minha teoria para isso é a seguinte: o seu script jquery nao encontra os elementos por que eles ainda nao foram carregados, isso por que o angular vai carregar seu template via ajax. Normalmente o jquery fica no `ready()`que é quando o dom esta pronto. É mais ou menos nesse ponto que o angular carrega seu template. Pelo menos acho que seja isso. Tenta dar uma debugada melhor e confirmar.

Comment: Tenta dar uma olhada nas diretivas do boostrap para angular: [link](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)